# How to transmit sound from Synthesizer to sequencer

Tags: java, audio, midi, synthesizer

Okay, this is my first question here so go easy on me guys. I'm trying to generate sound on the fly using the noteOn in the MidiChannel class with the internal Java Synthesizer. It produces sound perfectly. My problem is outputing that sound to my sequencer so I can save it to a midi file. At the moment, my program creates the file but its empty. The disconnect occurs with my transmitter/receiver setup. When I try to get the synth's transmitter, it produces the lovely MidiUnavailbleException.

I have a crapload of code in here so I'll just give you the highlights. The complete class will be at the very bottom.

```
public Piano()
{

    try 
    {
        //previous code not shown//

        sequence = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ, 4); //I know. Just let it be.
        
        sequence.createTrack();
        
        sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
        
        sequencer.open();
        
        sequencer.setSequence(sequence);
        
        sequencer.recordEnable(sequencer.getSequence().getTracks()[0], 1);
            
        receiver = sequencer.getReceiver();
        
        transmitter = synth.getTransmitter();
        
        transmitter.setReceiver(receiver);

    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

When it hits the `transmitter = synth.getTransmitter();`, I get the MidiUnavailableException. Any ideas on how to get the MidiEvents from my synth to the sequencer?

### //Complete Class - Warning: May Cause Headaches and/or Hysteria

```
package main;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.List;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.sound.midi.*;
import javax.sound.midi.MidiDevice.Info;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFileFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.Mixer;
import javax.sound.sampled.TargetDataLine;
import javax.swing.*;

import org.jfugue.DeviceThatWillReceiveMidi;
import org.jfugue.DeviceThatWillTransmitMidi;

public class Piano implements ActionListener
![enter image description here][2]{
        KeyEventDispatcher dispatcher = new KeyEventDispatcher()
{
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e)
    {           
        if(e.getID()==401)
        {
            if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
            {
                sustain();
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_PERIOD)
            {
                octaveUp();
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_COMMA)
            {
                octaveDown();
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_A)
            {
                start(freq);
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_W)
            {
                start(freq+1);
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_S)
            {
                start(freq+2);
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_E)
            {
                start(freq+3);
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_D)
            {
                start(freq+4);
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_F)
            {
                start(freq+5);
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_T)
            {
                start(freq+6);
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_G)
            {
                start(freq+7);
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_Y)
            {
                start(freq+8);
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_H)
            {
                start(freq+9);
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_U)
            {
                start(freq+10);
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_J)
            {
                start(freq+11);
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_K)
            {
                start(freq+12);
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_O)
            {
                start(freq+13);
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_L)
            {
                start(freq+14);
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_P)
            {
                start(freq+15);
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON)
            {
                start(freq+16);
            }
        }

        if(e.getID()==402)
        {
            if(!sustain)
            {

                if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_A)
                {
                    end(freq);
                }
                if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_W)
                {
                    end(freq+1);
                }
                if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_S)
                {
                    end(freq+2);
                }
                if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_E)
                {
                    end(freq+3);
                }
                if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_D)
                {
                    end(freq+4);
                }
                if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_F)
                {
                    end(freq+5);
                }
                if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_T)
                {
                    end(freq+6);
                }
                if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_G)
                {
                    end(freq+7);
                }
                if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_Y)
                {
                    end(freq+8);
                }
                if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_H)
                {
                    end(freq+9);
                }
                if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_U)
                {
                    end(freq+10);
                }
                if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_J)
                {
                    end(freq+11);
                }
                if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_K)
                {
                    end(freq+12);
                }
                if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_O)
                {
                    end(freq+13);
                }
                if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_L)
                {
                    end(freq+14);
                }
                if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_P)
                {
                    end(freq+15);
                }
                if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON)
                {
                    end(freq+16);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_A)
                {
                    endSoft(freq);
                }
                if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_W)
                {
                    endSoft(freq+1);
                }
                if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_S)
                {
                    endSoft(freq+2);
                }
                if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_E)
                {
                    endSoft(freq+3);
                }
                if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_D)
                {
                    endSoft(freq+4);
                }
                if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_F)
                {
                    endSoft(freq+5);
                }
                if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_T)
                {
                    endSoft(freq+6);
                }
                if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_G)
                {
                    endSoft(freq+7);
                }
                if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_Y)
                {
                    endSoft(freq+8);
                }
                if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_H)
                {
                    endSoft(freq+9);
                }
                if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_U)
                {
                    endSoft(freq+10);
                }
                if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_J)
                {
                    endSoft(freq+11);
                }
                if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_K)
                {
                    endSoft(freq+12);
                }
                if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_O)
                {
                    endSoft(freq+13);
                }
                if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_L)
                {
                    endSoft(freq+14);
                }
                if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_P)
                {
                    endSoft(freq+15);
                }
                if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON)
                {
                    endSoft(freq+16);
                }

            }
        }

        return false;

    }
};

final int VOLUME_MAX = 120;

int freq = 60;

int volume = VOLUME_MAX;

int instr; 

int delay = 1000;

int velocity = 1000;

int count = 0;

boolean sustain = false;

boolean recording = false;

DecimalFormat df;

List<Icon> icons;

AnimatedIcon aIcon;

Synthesizer synth;

Sequence sequence;

Sequencer sequencer;

MidiChannel[] mc;

Instrument[] instruments;

Instrument instrument;

Transmitter transmitter;

Receiver receiver;

File file;

JFrame mainFrame;

JPanel mainPanel;

ImagePanel iPanel;

JButton rec;

JButton stop;

JButton load;

JButton sustainB;

JButton octave;

JButton up;

JButton down;

JButton volumeB;

JButton vUp;

JButton vDown;

OctavePanel oPanel;

VolumePanel vPanel;

GridBagLayout gridBag;

GridBagConstraints c;

Image redCir;

Image greenCir;

Image recCir;

public Piano()
{
    DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().
    addKeyEventDispatcher(dispatcher);

    InputMap im = (InputMap)UIManager.get("Button.focusInputMap");
    im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("pressed SPACE"), "none");
    im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released SPACE"), "none");

    try 
    {
        synth = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer();

        synth.open();

        FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(this.getClass().getResource("resources/soundbank1.gm").toString().substring(6));

        Soundbank sBank = MidiSystem.getSoundbank(stream);

        instruments = sBank.getInstruments();

        synth.loadAllInstruments(sBank);

        mc = synth.getChannels();

        instrument = (Instrument)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Choose an instrument", "", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, instruments, instruments[0]);

        mc[0].programChange(instrument.getPatch().getProgram());

        greenCir = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("resources/greenCir.gif"));

        redCir  = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("resources/redCir.gif"));

        recCir = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("resources/rec.gif"));

        sequence = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ, 4);
        
        sequence.createTrack();
        
        sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
        
        sequencer.open();
        
        sequencer.setSequence(sequence);
        
        sequencer.recordEnable(sequencer.getSequence().getTracks()[0], 1);
        
        df = new DecimalFormat("000");
        
        receiver = sequencer.getReceiver();
        
        transmitter = synth.getTransmitter();
        
        transmitter.setReceiver(receiver);

    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void sustain()
{
    sustain = !sustain;

    if(sustain)
    {
        sustainB.setIcon(new ImageIcon(greenCir));
    }
    else
    {
        sustainB.setIcon(new ImageIcon(redCir));
    }
}

public void octaveUp()
{
    freq += 12;

    octave.setText("Octave: " + (freq-60)/12);
}

public void octaveDown()
{
    freq -= 12;

    octave.setText("Octave: " + (freq-60)/12);
}

public void vUp()
{
    if(volume < 120)
        volume += 12;

    volumeB.setText(setVText(volume));
}

public void vDown()
{
    if(volume > 0)
        volume -= 12;

    volumeB.setText(setVText(volume));
}

public void resetVolume()
{
    volume = VOLUME_MAX;
    volumeB.setText(setVText(volume));
}

public String setVText(int v)
{
    return "Volume " + volume/12 * 10 + "%";
}

public void selectInstrument()
{
    instrument = (Instrument)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Choose an instrument", "", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, instruments, instruments[0]);

    mc[0].programChange(instrument.getPatch().getProgram());
}

public BufferedImage getPiano()
{
    URL url = this.getClass().getResource("piano.gif");


    try 
    {

        BufferedImage buffImage = ImageIO.read(url);

        return buffImage;
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        System.out.println("Error");

        return null;
    }
}

public void start(int note)
{
    mc[0].noteOn(note, volume);     
}

public void end(int note)
{
    mc[0].noteOff(note);
}

public void endSoft(int note)
{
    //mc[0].noteOff(note, velocity);
}

public void createAndShowGUI()
{   
    mainFrame = new JFrame("Piano Maestro");
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(0);
    mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() 
    {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {System.exit(0);}
    });

    setupFrame(mainFrame.getContentPane());

    mainFrame.pack();
    mainFrame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500, 300));
    mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    mainFrame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(iPanel.getWidth()+20, mainFrame.getHeight()));

    mainFrame.setResizable(false);
}

public void setupFrame(Container pane)
{
    gridBag = new GridBagLayout();

    pane.setLayout(gridBag);

    c = new GridBagConstraints();

    sustainB = new JButton("Sustain");
    sustainB.addActionListener(this);
    sustainB.setActionCommand("sustain");

    up = new JButton();
    up.addActionListener(this);
    up.setActionCommand("up");

    down = new JButton();
    down.addActionListener(this);
    down.setActionCommand("down");

    octave = new JButton("Octave: 0");
    octave.addActionListener(this);
    octave.setActionCommand("resetOctave");

    stop = new JButton("Stop");
    stop.addActionListener(this);
    stop.setActionCommand("stop");

    rec = new JButton("rec");
    rec.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){rec();}});

    load = new JButton("Load Instr.");
    load.addActionListener(this);
    load.setActionCommand("load");

    volumeB = new JButton(setVText(volume));
    volumeB.addActionListener(this);
    volumeB.setActionCommand("resetVolume");

    vUp = new JButton();
    vUp.addActionListener(this);
    vUp.setActionCommand("vUp");

    vDown = new JButton();
    vDown.addActionListener(this);
    vDown.setActionCommand("vDown");

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.weightx = 1;
    c.ipady = 10;

    vPanel = new VolumePanel(vDown,volumeB,vUp);

    pane.add(vPanel,c);

    c.gridy = 1;

    oPanel = new OctavePanel(down,octave,up);

    pane.add(oPanel,c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 0;

    pane.add(sustainB,c);

    c.gridx = 2;

    pane.add(rec,c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 1;

    pane.add(load,c);

    c.gridx = 2;

    pane.add(stop,c);

    c.gridy = 2;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridwidth = 3;

    try 
    {

        sustainB.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("resources/redCir.gif"))));

        up.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("resources/up.gif"))));

        vUp.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("resources/up.gif"))));

        down.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("resources/down.gif"))));

        vDown.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("resources/down.gif"))));

        stop.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("resources/square.gif"))));

        rec.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("resources/rec.gif"))));

        iPanel = new ImagePanel("resources/piano.gif");

        pane.add(iPanel,c);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    aIcon = new AnimatedIcon(rec,750,1,new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("resources/recOn.gif")),new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("resources/recOff.gif")));

    load.setPreferredSize(sustainB.getPreferredSize());

    rec.setPreferredSize(stop.getPreferredSize());

    octave.setPreferredSize(volumeB.getPreferredSize());

    volumeB.setPreferredSize(volumeB.getPreferredSize());

    volumeB.setText(setVText(volume));
}

public void rec()
{
    recording = true;

    rec.setIcon(aIcon);

    aIcon.start();

    sequencer.startRecording();

}

public void stop()
{
    if(recording)
    {
        aIcon.stop();

        rec.setIcon(new ImageIcon(recCir));

        sequencer.stop();

        if(sequence!=null)
        {
            file = new File("Song" + df.format(count) + ".midi");

            while(file.exists())
            {
                count++;

                file = new File("Song" + df.format(count) + ".midi");
            }

            try 
            {
                MidiSystem.write(sequence, 1, file);
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your system is unable to write files.","Error",2);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your system is unable to write files.","Error",2);
        }
    }

    mc[0].allNotesOff();

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{

    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("sustain"))
    {
        sustain();
    }
    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("up"))
    {
        octaveUp();
    }
    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("down"))
    {
        octaveDown();
    }
    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("resetOctave"))
    {
        freq = 60;
        octave.setText("Octave: " + (freq-60)/12);
    }
    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("load"))
    {
        this.selectInstrument();
    }
    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("piano"))
    {
        mc[0].programChange(instruments[0].getPatch().getProgram());
    }
    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("stop"))
    {
        stop();
    }
    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("vUp"))
    {
        vUp();
    }
    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("vDown"))
    {
        vDown();
    }
    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("resetVolume"))
    {
        resetVolume();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear.  Can you clarify?  MIDI doesn't deal with sound at all, so by saying you want to redirect sound with MIDI, that it isn't possible.  It sounds like you simply want to send MIDI messages to a MIDI interface where your synthesizer is connected.  Is that the case?  Or, are you trying to write a MIDI file?  And if so, what difference does it make what device is connected?

Comment: I used java's internal synth to create sound. It will play the sound on the computer's speakers. I am currently trying to export that sound/midi note into a midi file.